# On a stop in Amsterdam with KLM, if I want to visit the city, must I pay another boarding fee when coming back to airport?

Tags: air-travel, europe, stopovers, fees-and-charges, klm

I'm planning a journey during my next vacation in Febuary 2013 from São Paulo to Paris. In one of my researches, I found a good flight option with KLM. The plane stops for 6 hours in Amsterdam (Netherlands) with all fees/taxes included. My doubt is, will I need to pay another boarding fee if, during this stop, I get out of Amsterdam airport to visit the city? Last year I did the same with TAP in Lisbon and had no problems with it.

Comment: Why would you need to pay a boarding fee?

Comment: You might want to check http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/3523/141.

Comment: @Andra Wow, yes, I want :D Thank you very much. Amazing post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you will not need to pay any additional fees.

Any applicable airport tax will be included in your ticket and is irrelevant to whether you spend the entire 6 hours inside Schiphol's security zone or if you use some of it to venture outside the airport.

It is entirely at your discretion how you spend that time. Just make sure you are back in time to pass through security in time to catch your flight.

Comment: This answer is correct.

Comment: Depending on your citizenship, remember to double-check on the need for visas etc. if you plan to leave the airport.

Comment: For what it's worth: I flew KLM from FWA to IST.  Instead of a five-hour layover in AMS, I bought the ticket with a 53-hour layover and got a good long look at Amsterdam.  Same fare.