# Amsterdam - How to reach the Iamsterdam square from Schipol airport and back in less than 3 hours?

Tags: budget, trains, amsterdam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [5 hours in Amsterdam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3521/5-hours-in-amsterdam)

I have a trip planned for next febuary to Paris with a step over Amsterdam (KLM flight) of 5 hours and I'm thinking on visit some interesting attractions close to the Iamsterdam square on Amsterdam city. By looking on internet, I could not find a metro/train option to go from Schipol airport directly to that reagion.

What are my options? What are the cheap options to go there and come back in less than 3 hours?

Comment: Is there a typo in the name of the square you want to visit? Only Google can't seem to find it

Comment: @Gagravarr Museumplein.

Comment: I think it's this [square](http://hostelsclubblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/i-amsterdam-letters-museumplein-edwin-van-eis_001.jpg)

Comment: Exactly. Iamsterdam square :D

Comment: Specifically for this question: Busline 197 departs from Schiphol and deposits you on Museumplein in 30 minutes for 6EUR(-ish) both ways.